# Grails, Spring Security Rest Plugin, Cannot invoke method loadUserByToken() on null object

Tags: grails, spring-security, spring-security-rest

I am trying implement token based authentication using Spring Security Plugin (2.0.0) and Spring Authentication Rest Plugin(1.5.3) in grails framework(2.5.0). I set header field "x-auth-token" to token and post to target controller URL. However, IDE (Intellij IDEA) pop out this error message

```
| Error 2016-07-12 15:58:27,864 [http-bio-8080-exec-10] ERROR [/hello_world].
[default]  - Servlet.service() for servlet [default] in context with path [/hello_world] threw exception
Message: Cannot invoke method loadUserByToken() on null object
Line | Method
->>   55 | authenticate in grails.plugin.springsecurity.rest.RestAuthenticationProvider
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|     75 | doFilter     in grails.plugin.springsecurity.rest.RestTokenValidationFilter
|     53 | doFilter . . in grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.filter.GrailsAnonymousAuthenticationFilter
|    143 | doFilter     in grails.plugin.springsecurity.rest.RestAuthenticationFilter
|     62 | doFilter . . in grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.authentication.logout.MutableLogoutFilter
|     80 | doFilter     in grails.plugin.springsecurity.rest.RestLogoutFilter
|     59 | doFilter . . in grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.SecurityRequestHolderFilter
|     82 | doFilter     in com.brandseye.cors.CorsFilter
|   1142 | runWorker .  in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    617 | run          in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    745 | run . . . .  in java.lang.Thread
```

I checked this loadUserByToken() method and it is invoked on tokenStorageService. I have no idea why this tokenStorageService is null object. The Spring Security and Spring Security Plugin are configured as follows:

Config.groovy

```
// Added by the Spring Security Core plugin:
grails.plugin.springsecurity.userLookup.userDomainClassName = 'hello_world.User'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.userLookup.authorityJoinClassName = 'hello_world.UserRole'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.authority.className = 'hello_world.Role'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.controllerAnnotations.staticRules = [
    '/':                ['permitAll'],
    '/index':           ['permitAll'],
    '/index.gsp':       ['permitAll'],
    '/assets/**':       ['permitAll'],
    '/**/js/**':        ['permitAll'],
    '/**/css/**':       ['permitAll'],
    '/**/images/**':    ['permitAll'],
    '/**/favicon.ico':  ['permitAll'],
    '/api/login':       ['permitAll']
]

grails {
    plugin {
        springsecurity {

            filterChain.chainMap = [
                    '/api/guest/**': 'anonymousAuthenticationFilter,restTokenValidationFilter,restExceptionTranslationFilter,filterInvocationInterceptor',
                    '/api/**': 'JOINED_FILTERS,-exceptionTranslationFilter,-authenticationProcessingFilter,-securityContextPersistenceFilter,-rememberMeAuthenticationFilter',  // Stateless chain
                    '/**': 'JOINED_FILTERS,-restTokenValidationFilter,-restExceptionTranslationFilter'                                                                          // Traditional chain
            ]

            providerNames = ['restAuthenticationProvider','daoAuthenticationProvider', 'rememberMeAuthenticationProvider']

            auth.loginFormUrl = '/login/auth'

            useSecurityEventListener = true

            onAuthenticationSuccessEvent = { e, appCtx ->
                // handle AuthenticationSuccessEvent

                System.out.println("Authentication Succeeded");
            }

            onAuthenticationSwitchUserEvent = { e, appCtx ->
                // handle AuthenticationSwitchUserEvent
            }

            onAuthorizationEvent = { e, appCtx ->
                // handle AuthorizationEvent
            }

            onRestTokenCreationEvent = { e, appCtx ->

                System.out.println("Token Created")
            }

            apf {
                filterProcessesUrl = '/api/login'
                allowSessionCreation = false
//                usernamePropertyName = 'username'
//                passwordPropertyName = 'password'
            }

            rest {

                active = true

                login {
                    active = true
                    endpointUrl = '/api/login'
                    failureStatusCode = 401
                    useJsonCredentials = true
                    usernamePropertyName = 'username'
                    passwordPropertyName = 'password'
                }

                token {

                    validation {
                        active = true
                        endpointUrl = '/api/validate'
                        headerName = 'x-auth-token'
                        useBearerToken = false
                        tokenPropertyName = 'access_token'
                        enableAnonymousAccess = true
                    }

                    generation {
                        active = true
                        useSecureRandom = true
                        useUUID = false
                    }

                    rendering {
                        usernamePropertyName = 'username'
                        authoritiesPropertyName = 'roles'
                        tokenPropertyName = 'token'
                    }

                    storage {
                        active = true
                        useGorm = true

                        gorm {
                            tokenDomainClassName = 'hello_world.AuthenticationToken'
                            tokenValuePropertyName = 'tokenValue'
                            usernamePropertyName = 'username'
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

resources.groovy

```
import grails.plugin.springsecurity.rest.RestAuthenticationProvider
beans = {
    restAuthenticationProvider(RestAuthenticationProvider);
}
```

and I have checked database, the token is stored in authentication_token table. I am new to grails and have been searching hours and no clue at all. Can anyone help me? much appreciated.

If you need anything else, please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For someone who has the same issue, after a number of tryings, I finally figured this out. It seems that I shouldn't declare restAuthenticationProvider in resources.groovy and shouldn't add restAuthenticationProvider to grails.plugin.springsecurity.providerNames in config.groovy. The complete configs for spring-security-core and spring-security-rest are listed as follows:

config.groovy

```
grails {
    plugin {
        springsecurity {

            useSecurityEventListener = true

            filterChain {
                chainMap = [
                        '/api/**': 'JOINED_FILTERS,-exceptionTranslationFilter,-authenticationProcessingFilter,-securityContextPersistenceFilter,-rememberMeAuthenticationFilter',  // Stateless chain
                        '/**': 'JOINED_FILTERS,-restTokenValidationFilter,-restExceptionTranslationFilter'                                                                          // Traditional chain
                ]
            } //filterChain

            apf {
                filterProcessesUrl = '/api/login'
            } //apf

            rest {

                login {
                    active = true
                    useRequestParamsCredentials = false
                    useJsonCredentials = true
                    usernamePropertyName = 'j_username'
                    passwordPropertyName = 'j_password'
                    endpointUrl = '/api/login'
                } //login

                logout {

                } //logout

                token {

                    validation {
                        active = true
                        endpointUrl = '/api/validate'
                        useBearerToken = false
                        headername = 'X-Auth-Token'
                    } //validation

                    generation {
//                        active = true
//                        useSecureRandom = true;
//                        useUUID = false;
                    }

                    rendering {
                        usernamePropertyName = 'username'
                        authoritiesPropertyName = 'roles'
                        tokenPropertyName = 'token'
                    }

                    storage {
//                        useJWT = true;
                    } //storage
                } //token
            } //rest

            cors.headers = ['Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Content-Type, Authorization, X-Auth-Token']
        } //springsecurity
    } //plugin
} //grails
```

you should send username and password in json format with field "j_username" and "j_password" and it will return a token in json format. Then, send request together with this token in the header field "X-Auth-Token" to the api you want to query.

For initializing the spring-security-core plugin, please consult http://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-spring-security-core/v2/guide/single.html#tutorials

a complete of my code is available in github: https://github.com/xixinhe/api_token_authentication

Before running my code, please install oracle mysql 5.

If there is anything I wrote violating the stack overflow rules, please let me know, I will change.

I am not a native English speaker, please forgive me crappy English.

Thanks,